# .NET 6.0 - read appsettings.json values from class library

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

.NET 6.0 - get appsettings.json values from class library. I have a .NET 6.0 web api project and another is class library.

I want to read some settings into class library.

We have appsettings.json inside a web api project.
How can I read those values inside a class library?

Could you please provide me proper code snippets

I am new to .net core 6 and also dependency injections and all

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you have already asked this question multiple times (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70263655/net-6-0-get-appsettings-json-values-from-class-library)) .

Answer (score 4):

In your class library where you want to read in the values, you should be able to access the json-file with `ConfigurationBuilder`. First, define location of appsettings.json:

`string filePath = @"C:\MyDir\MySubDirWhereAppSettingsIsLocated\appSettings.json"; //this is where appSettings.json is located`

Then use the `filePath` when trying to access file:

```
IConfiguration myConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(filePath))
   .AddJsonFile("appSettings.json")
   .Build();
```

Then afterwards, you can access the individual values inside `appsettings.json` like this:

`string myValue = myConfig.GetValue<string>("nameOfMyValue");`

Beware that you need to import the NuGet-package `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json`

Comment: I would argue that in general you should avoid reading settings in the class library project but rather expose some API to pass parsed ones to the library.

Comment: You also need package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

Comment: @Maze90 I currently use the above solution in one of my projects without reference to `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` - solely `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration`.

Comment: @GuruStron That sounds like a good approach. If you have a link to an example, I would be keen to see it.

Comment: @mnc There is not much to show in example. The idea is as simple as it sounds. See the `ExampleService` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/options#bind-hierarchical-configuration) (possibly without `IOptions`). Basically the service can be located inside the library and hosting project is responsible for instantiation (via DI or manually) and providing the settings (again - via DI or manually).

Comment: @GuruStron Cool, wasn't familiar with it. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: Are you going to harcode the file path? This should be dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if your class library has its appsettings.json at the base directory, you can do this:

```
public class ConnectionStringProvider : IConnectionStringProvider
{
    public string ConnStrName1 { get; set; }
    public string ConnStrName2 { get; set; }
    public string ConnStr1 { get; set; }
    public string ConnStr2 { get; set; }
    public string Connstr3 { get; set; }
    public IConfigurationRoot configuration { get; set; }

    public ConnectionStringProvider()
    {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
        .Build();
        ConnStrName1 = "ConnectionStringName1";
        ConnStrName2 = "ConnectionStringName2";
        ConnStr1 = configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnStrName1);
        ConnStr2 = configuration.GetConnectionString(ConnStrName2);
        Connstr3 = configuration.GetConnectionString("LocalConnStringName");
    }
}
```